# In array find match and replace it by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here have a array set:

```
totalarray =[
             [1,2,3,4],
             [8,9,10],     
             [15,16,17],
             [8,14,20]
            ]
```

And I need to make it combine if which set have a same number.

like that:

```
totalarray =[
             [1,2,3,4],
             [8,9,10,14,20],
             [15,16,17]
            ]
```

Other example:

```
totalarray =[
[1,2,3,4],
[6,10,19],
[6,16,4],
[4,14,20]
]
```

to

```
totalarray =[
[1,2,3,4,6,10,14,16,19,20]
]
```

So, I need to make it if any number match on other array and make it to together. e.g:

```
Array = [[1,2,3,4],[8,9,10],[8,11,12]];
```

`Array[1][0]` and `Array[2][0]` is match, so Array will become `Array = [1,2,3,4],[8,9,10,11,12].`

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You mean which has a repeated number ? Can you explain more please?

Comment: Sorry, I need to make it if any number match on other array and make it to together. e.g: Array = [1,2,3,4],[8,9,10],[8,11,12]; Array[1][0] and Array[2][0] is match, so Array will become Array = [1,2,3,4],[8,9,10,11,12]. Thanks for fast reply.

Comment: so you want to join only the arrays that have a value in common? are you sure there's no better way to approach this? merge all arrays and remove duplicates for example?

Comment: Your second example seems wrong : there's no common value between the arrays 0+3 and the arrays 1+2.

Comment: How Array[1][0] and Array[2][0] can match?!

Comment: Sorry, now updated. Thanks for fast reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the boring looping code. But you might make it a little more manageable with

- `[].push.apply(arr1, arr2);` : it pushes all elements of `arr2` to `arr1` without building a new array
- [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) : it looks for an element in an array. If you want to support IE8, as you tagged the question [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), then you may use [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Here's the code :

```
var totalarray =[
  [1,2,3,4],
  [8,9,10],     
  [15,16,17],
  [8,14,20]
];
var result = [totalarray[0]];
function prec(tai) {
  for (var j=0; j<result.length; j++) {
    for (var k=0; k<tai.length; k++) {
      if (result[j].indexOf(tai[k])!=-1) {
        return result[j];
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
for (var i=1; i<totalarray.length; i++) {
  var arr = prec(totalarray[i]);
  if (arr) [].push.apply(arr, totalarray[i]);
  else result.push(totalarray[i]);
}
```

`result` is the array you want.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/okapeh/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you are trying to get union

You use the library ***underscore*** you can write like this

```
_.union([1, 2, 3], [101, 2, 1, 10], [2, 1]);
=> [1, 2, 3, 101, 10]
```

Link: [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#union)

Comment: Well, that really doesn't look like what OP asks for.